# Unpack values in ArrayType as columns in df

Tags: json, list, dataframe, pyspark

I have the below pyspark dataframe which i created by reading a JSON file and i want to unpack the values in column contents and use the keys as new columns and the values as values in the same dataframe. How could i do that? Do i have to modify the JSON file before i read it as a dataframe or can i do in as an operation on the dataframe?

json file structure:

```
{"account_id": "a01", "contents": [{"service_id": "S121", "price": 1256}, {"service_id": "S022", "price": 1149}], "date": "2020-03-22 05:53:53.358149"}

schema:
 |-- contents: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- price: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- service_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- account_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)

generated table:
+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
|            contents|account_id |    date            |
+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
|[[1256, S121],[11,..|        a01|2020-01-17 05:53:...|
|[[556, S03], [114...|        a01|2020-01-16 23:58:...|


and i would like it to be something like:
-----------+--------------------+-----+----------+
|account_id |    date            |price|service_id|
+-----------+--------------------+-----+----------+
|        a01|2020-01-17 05:53:...| 1256|      S121|
|        a01|2020-01-17 05:53:...|1149 |     S022 |
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are having `array column` needs to be **`exploded`** then select `*` from the struct column.

**`Example:`**

```
#sample df
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- account_id: string (nullable = true)
# |-- contents: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |-- price: long (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- service_id: string (nullable = true)
# |-- date: string (nullable = true)

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("arr",explode(col("contents"))).\
select("account_id","date","arr.*").\
show()
#+----------+--------------------------+-----+----------+
#|account_id|date                      |price|service_id|
#+----------+--------------------------+-----+----------+
#|a01       |2020-03-22 05:53:53.358149|1256 |S121      |
#|a01       |2020-03-22 05:53:53.358149|1149 |S022      |
#+----------+--------------------------+-----+----------+
```

Comment: @Shu he cant upvote until he gets 15 reputation, i got u